# Stop message from popping up constantly when error is detected

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a windows form application that allows users to convert currency. I currently am working on making sure the value passed to the converter is only a positive integer. I have a message that pops up whenever anything other than a positive integer is entered, but when i enter something like "a" it keeps popping up and wont let me enter any other values.

```
 public int USCurren(int value)
{
    bool MessageShown;
    string input = textBox1.Text;
        while(true)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(input, out value))
        {
            if (MessageShown = false && value <= 0)
            {
                MessageShown = true;
                MessageBox.Show("Please Input A Positive Integer");
                textBox1.Clear();
            }
            else
                return value;
            MessageShown = false;
        }
        else 
        {
            MessageShown = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Please Input A Positive Integer");
            textBox1.Clear();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this way,

```
public int USCurren()
    {
        string input = textBox1.Text;
        int value = -1;

        try
        {
            if (int.TryParse(input, out value) && value > 0)
            {
                //Write your code here to convert the currency;
                return value;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Input A Positive Integer");
                textBox1.Clear();
                value = -1;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Show exception here
        }
        return value;
    }
```

Comment: I tried this out, but now i'm getting an "not all code paths return a value" error. :P

Comment: I have updated the code. But still I can't get it, Why you need a while iteration here ?

Comment: Its how i avoid a crash when an improper input is put in, i have no idea how to handle errors like that otherwise.

Comment: Well, you can write your code inside a try catch block to avoid crash. I have updated  a simple code for this conversion.